# Php Regular expression code

Tags: php, regex, string, split

Can anyone have a look at the php code I wrote. I want to extract the three information into an array, but it doesn't work for me.

```
$string = "<Name>Joh Doe <Email>joh.doe@gmail.com <App ID> 130105"
$var = preg_split("/^<.*<$/" , $string);
```

Thanks,

Comment: oops! $var = preg_split("/^<.*<$/" , $string")

Comment: You can edit your question, you know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing delimitters which would result in:

```
Warning: preg_split() [function.preg-split]: No ending delimiter
```

Here is what you should have:

```
$string = "<Name>Joh Doe <Email>joh.doe@gmail.com <App ID> 130105";
$var = preg_split("#^<.*<$#" , $string);
print_r($var);
```

**Result:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Joh Doe joh.doe@gmail.com  130105
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Works great. What does # stand for?

Comment: @Sumit: It is demilitter. Most people use `/` but you can also use certain other characters such as `#`. I use that because it appears clearly and kind of tells it is delimitter :) All regex is put inside these delimitters.

Comment: How would that split do anything? It should not match. I think it's just your browser not displaying the tags.

Comment: Yeah, seems so. No idea what went wrong. Seems Sarfaraz has some charm in his name! Things started working.

Comment: Wrong result and it doesn't do anything at all except put the whole string as the first element in the array.

Comment: @Qtax: Ah I got it now. My answer answered his original question in which he was missing delimitters. Anyways nice to spot that regex part as well.

Comment: Missing delimiters is just one of several problems.  He should be using `preg_match` instead of `preg_split`; the second `<` should be `>`; the `.*` should be `.*?` or `[^>]+`; the anchors (`^` and `$`) shouldn't be there; and (as @Qtax pointed out) the resulting array should contain *three* elements, not just one.  With 88.5k rep, you should know better than to assume *anything* in an OP's code is correct. :P

Comment: @AlanMoore: I agree with you, I will have to take on ***regex*** seriously now :)

Answer (score 3):

```
$string = "<Name>Joh Doe <Email>joh.doe@gmail.com <App ID> 130105";
preg_match_all('/<([^>]*)>([^<]+)/' , $string, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

Gives:

```
array(3) {
  [0] => array(3) {
    [0] => string(14) "Joh Doe "
    [1] => string(25) "joh.doe@gmail.com "
    [2] => string(15) " 130105"
  }
  [1] => array(3) {
    [0] => string(4) "Name"
    [1] => string(5) "Email"
    [2] => string(6) "App ID"
  }
  [2] => array(3) {
    [0] => string(8) "Joh Doe "
    [1] => string(18) "joh.doe@gmail.com "
    [2] => string(7) " 130105"
  }
}
```

Comment: array
  0 => 
    array
      empty
  1 => 
    array
      empty
  2 => 
    array
      empty is the answer I got.

Comment: var_dump(matches); should of course be var_dump($matches);
But copy paste example above, should work fine

Answer (score 2):

Don't anchor the regex in the split, also the regex doesn't end with `<` but `>`.

```
$str = "<Name>Joh Doe <Email>joh.doe@gmail.com <App ID> 130105";
$arr = preg_split("/<[^>]+>/" , $str);
print_r($arr);
```

**output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] =>
    [1] => Joh Doe
    [2] => joh.doe@gmail.com
    [3] =>  130105
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use:

```
$string = "<Name>Joh Doe <Email>joh.doe@gmail.com <App ID> 130105";
preg_match_all('/>\s*([^<]+)/', $string, $var);

print_r($var[1]);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Joh Doe 
    [1] => joh.doe@gmail.com 
    [2] => 130105
)
```

Comment: @Sumit, show us your code. The above two lines of code work, just copy and paste.

Comment: include('simplehtmldom\simple_html_dom.php'); 
$html = file_get_html("file:///C:/Users/Ezio/Desktop/Flat.html"); 

$storage = $html -> find(".ms-disc-bordered-noleft");
$k=1;
while(isset($storage[$k]))
{
$string = strip_tags($storage[$k]);
preg_match_all('/>\s*([^<]+)/', $string, $var);
print_r($var[1]);

$k++;
}

Comment: `echo "str: '$string'\n";` obviously it doesn't contain what you think.

Comment: Any idea how to get rid of â€.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$string = "<Name>Joh Doe <Email>joh.doe@gmail.com <App ID> 130105";
$var = preg_split("#\s*<.*?>\s*#" , $string);
print_r($var);
```

Outputs:

> Array ( [0] => [1] => Joh Doe [2] => joh.doe@gmail.com [3] => 130105 )

The first index is empty because there is nothing before the first tag.

**Update**

As suggested by JRL

```
$var = preg_split("#\s*<.*?>\s*#" , $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

output:

> Array ( [0] => Joh Doe [1] => joh.doe@gmail.com [2] => 130105 )

Comment: To avoid the empty index, you can use the PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY tag.